# Regex not matching exact string when using \b

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match an exact string using regex (I cannot use a string comparison so please don't suggest that).

```
string regexValue = "CB/TF8/C9";
                
                bool test = Regex.IsMatch(
                    string.Join("\r\n", "This is the description CB/TTF8/C9 and this is more description CB/TF8/C9", "CCB/TF8/C9"),
                    regexValue ,
                    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                );
```

I want to match `CB/TF8/C9` exactly so it shouldn't match `CB/TTF8/C9` or `CCB/TF8/C9`. I have tried using `\bCB/TF8/C9\b` or `\\bCB/TF8/C9\\b` or `\\\bCB/TF8/C9\\\b` and can't get anything to match. Could someone please tell me what regex is needed for the `test` to return true.

Comment: 1. you should simplify the question. 
2. i test regexpressions in https://regex101.com/ it does not have a c# regex flavor which sometimes makes a difference.

Comment: [Works in a .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbCB%2fTF8%2fC9%5cb&i=This+is+the+description+CB%2fTTF8%2fC9+and+this+is+more+description+CB%2fTF8%2fC9%0d%0aCCB%2fTF8%2fC9&o=icm), and it worked when I tested it [in code](https://rextester.com/WAV83805). Did you perhaps forget that `"\b"` will be interpreted as an escaped character in a C# string literal unless you write it as `@"\b"`?

Comment: With the code you've provided it already returns `True`. Did you test before posting?

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code exactly as you have it, it matches.

You are trying to match `"CB/TF8/C9"` against this string:

```
This is the description CB/TTF8/C9 and this is more description CB/TF8/C9
CCB/TF8/C9
```

Since the your string contains exactly `"CB/TF8/C9"` it matches. And it doesn't matter how many `\b` you put in the front or back of the Regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `\bCB/TF8/C9\b` worked for me in [Regexr](https://regexr.com/). Maybe you should try to escape the special characters in your `regexValue`.

Like this: `string regexValue = @"\bCB/TF8/C9\b";`